# Write YUY2 textures from HLSL Compute Shader

Tags: graphics, directx-11, hlsl

I want to write a shader to analyze and transform video data in YUY2 format. Since shaders do not support YUY2 format textures, I'm using different views for the shader. The input texture is a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_B8G8_UNORM` shader resource view, and the output texture is a `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT` unordered access view to allow for writing.

The problem I have is that writes to the output texture don't do anything. I've simplified my compute shader down to just writing a constant value to the output texture, but no matter what value I write, the output texture is just solid green.

Here's my setup code:

```
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext4> context;
{
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> c;
    m_Device->GetImmediateContext(&c);
    ThrowHR(c.QueryInterface(&context));
}


// Create texture & view for input frame

CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> frameTexture;
CComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> frameView;
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC frameDesc = {};
    frameDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    frameDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    frameDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    frameDesc.Height = frame.Height;
    frameDesc.Width = frame.Width;
    frameDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    frameDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    frameDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    frameDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    frameDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    frameDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA frameInit = {};
    frameInit.pSysMem = frame.Data;
    frameInit.SysMemPitch = UINT(frame.Width * 2);
    frameInit.SysMemSlicePitch = (UINT)frame.Size;

    ThrowHR(m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&frameDesc, &frameInit, &frameTexture));

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC frameViewDesc = {};
    frameViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_B8G8_UNORM; // Analog to YUY2 which is supported by SRVs
    frameViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    frameViewDesc.Texture2D = { 0, 1 };

    ThrowHR(m_Device->CreateShaderResourceView(frameTexture, &frameViewDesc, &frameView));
}

// Create texture & view for output frame

CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> outputTexture;
CComPtr<ID3D11UnorderedAccessView> outputView;
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC outputDesc = {};
    outputDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    outputDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    outputDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    outputDesc.Height = frame.Height;
    outputDesc.Width = frame.Width;
    outputDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    outputDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    outputDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    outputDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    outputDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    outputDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2;

    ThrowHR(m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&outputDesc, nullptr, &outputTexture));

    D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc = {};
    uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT; // Supported Read/Write format for UAV 
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    uavDesc.Texture2D = { 0 };

    ThrowHR(m_Device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(outputTexture, &uavDesc, &outputView));
}

// Bind shader resources
context->CSSetShader(m_ComputeShader, nullptr, 0);
ID3D11Buffer *const cbufs[] = { m_ParamsCBuffer };
context->CSSetConstantBuffers(0, ARRAYSIZE(cbufs), cbufs);
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView *const uavs[] = { m_StatsView, outputView };
context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, ARRAYSIZE(uavs), uavs, nullptr);
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *const srvs[] = { frameView };
context->CSSetShaderResources(0, ARRAYSIZE(srvs), srvs);

// Execute shader
context->Dispatch(frame.Width / 2, frame.Height, 1);

// Unbind shader
ZeroMemory((void*)cbufs, sizeof(cbufs));
context->CSSetConstantBuffers(0, ARRAYSIZE(cbufs), cbufs);
ZeroMemory((void*)uavs, sizeof(uavs));
context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, ARRAYSIZE(uavs), uavs, nullptr);
ZeroMemory((void*)srvs, sizeof(srvs));
context->CSSetShaderResources(0, ARRAYSIZE(srvs), srvs);
context->CSSetShader(nullptr, nullptr, 0);
```

And here's the shader:

```
// R8G8_B8G8_UNORM view into YUY2
Texture2D<unorm float4> Input : register(t0);

// R32_UINT view into YUY2
RWTexture2D<uint> Output : register(u1);

// Packs an X8Y8Z8W8_UNORM float4 into a uint
uint packFloat4(float4 unpacked)
{
    uint output;
    uint x = (uint)(clamp(unpacked.x, 0, 1) * 255) << 0;
    uint y = (uint)(clamp(unpacked.y, 0, 1) * 255) << 8;
    uint z = (uint)(clamp(unpacked.z, 0, 1) * 255) << 16;
    uint w = (uint)(clamp(unpacked.w, 0, 1) * 255) << 24;
    return x + y + z + w;
}

// Processes two adjacent pixels at a time due to YUY2 packing
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void main(uint3 gid : SV_GroupID)
{
    unorm float4 outPixel = float4(0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0);
    uint outPacked = packFloat4(outPixel);
    Output[gid.xy] = outPacked;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a DEBUG DX device to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Additionally you might need x | y | z | w instead of x + y + z + w.

Comment: @VuVirt yes, I use a debug device.

Comment: You may want to try using the Graphics Debugging Tools in Visual Studio. Once you capture a "frame", you'll be able to run the shader debugger and see whether or not your shader is actually doing a write, and where that write is occurring. It may be that your thread dispatch parameters are messed up, so your shader is continually updating the same pixel instead of all your pixels.You may also want to check the binary values of the output image's pixels - if they happen to be a consistent, repeating pattern, that can provide more clues to properly diagnose the problem.